# Empty values being added to all mysql rows instead of just the target row

Tags: php, mysql

Empty columns are being added to my MySQL rows upon submitting data into my server. I am entering it into one row but all rows get at least an empty column. How can I prevent this? Here is an example. Any that say 0bytes are empty rows.

[image: See empty rows?]

My PHP code so far (will be chamged when I figure out this part)

```
<?php
    $servername = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $username = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question
    $password = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question  
    $dbname = ""; //Taken out for stack overflow question

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['cf'] && $_POST['category']))
        {
            /*foreach($_FILES['cf']['name'] as $key => $name)
            {
                if ($_FILES['cf']['error'][$key] == 0)
                {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "");
                }
            }*/
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $cf = $_FILES['cf'];
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.") VALUES(8)");
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Empty file';
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want to prevent those empty rows. In my recover php file when I retrieve them from the server, I wrap the content in a `<img>` tag so anything taken from those rows are displayed as an image. I don't want the corrupted image or an empty frame to show with the rest of the ads. How can I stop this?

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the rows you've shown are empty.

Comment: Columns in the rows are empty.

Comment: It appears you are only inserting in a single column for any particular row; of course the other fields are empty. _You cannot have the columns exist for some rows and not exist for others._

Comment: But then an image image frame will appear in the html. Because of how the string is in the retrieve.php

Comment: category is the name of the select tag in the html file.

Comment: So you are saying they have 0 byte contents, rather than null contents? Are you sure it is not just how your code is interpreting the results? (BLOB fields cannot have a default value set, they automatically default to NULL.)

Comment: Yup 0 Byes. My code is up there if there was something wrong with the query. All programming is done in that file

Comment: I have printed the value of $category it does return the correct value that is selected.

Comment: What are the default values for those columns when you defined the table in database?

Comment: The code you've shown is incomplete; we're not shown where you are getting the values back out, and the existence of first two rows shown in the image (3 and 4) are impossible with the code you've shown.

Comment: No they aren't. Inputting images is actually my next question because it seems to have a different process. So I am just inputting 8 into the category. Also the options in it are food, software, hardware, home, outdoor, indooract, services, and other

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to print out the contents of category to the console? Is it possible that a valid category and a null category is being posted back from the source?

you could also try encapulating the sql call with a nul check against the category. This might catch the null before its inserted.

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$cf = $_FILES['cf'];

if($category != NULL)
{
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.") VALUES(8)");
}
```

Lastly you could set one of the columns in the table to not allow null values. Which would allow you to put a try catch block and dispose of the empty data

```
Try {
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO adDatabase(".$category.") VALUES(8)");
} 
catch (exception ex)
{
    // do nothing!
}
```

Comment: They are not null. The value is going into the database. It creates empty values though.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you do an `insert` query, sql will insert a whole row. if you only specify one column then all the other columns will be filled with `null` (or whatever the default value is).

if you want to fill the other columns in the row you can do that..

```
insert into table (col1, col2) values ('val1', 'val2')
```

If you wan tto update a column in an existing row..

```
Update table set column = 'value' where col='somevalue'
```

bottom line is, you can;t create a row and expect only a single column to be populated. that makes no sense.. where you expecting something like this to happen?

[image]

Comment: So updating it will make the 0B turn to null?

Comment: How do I target only one column instead of a row?

Comment: honestly, your question is beyond the scope of what stack overflow was intended to do. you're not asking a specific question, you're asking for someone to explain the whole concept of sql to you. you really need to read a tutorial or two and grasp the concept before trying to use it.

Comment: -.- I know MySQL. I just usually don't create a table for images. Therefore I don't know how to upload images.

Comment: It is a simple question how do I target a specific column.

Comment: obviously all the columns are blob types. if the blob size is zero (as indicated by `[BLOB - 0 B]` then it is empty. your code already targets a specific column. which part is confusing?

Comment: I retrieves the column and places it as an empty image frame.